# Тип переменной register

Tags: c++, c, типы-данных, типы

Какой тип у переменной объявленной с ключевым словом `register`?

Встретил такой код. Какой тут тип у переменной `n`?

```
int main() {
    register n;
}
```

Comment: это невалидный код, так как тип переменной в объявлении не указан. Ключевое слово `register` в языке больше ничего не делает

Comment: Это int. (в С, не в C++.)

Comment: @user7860670 с мощью `gcc` компилируется, с помощью `g++` нет

Comment: в gcc он скомпилируется только с игнорированием предупреждений

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Register - это класс памяти объектов в си, он означает, что число перемещается в регистр. Вроде как от этого с ним
операции проходят быстрее.

Также , как верно отметил avp:

`register` всегда был хинтом (hint, совет). Компилятор не обязан помещать такую переменную в регистр, но вправе прислушаться к такому совету, по крайней мере при оптимизации  такая переменная будет более приоритетна для размещения в регистре, чем другие. / И еще, по крайней мере в старом Си тип int существовал по умолчанию (как минимум как тип возвращаемого функцией значения), поэтому его можно было не указывать вместе с хинтом

А вообще по умолчанию здесь тип int, как если бы ты написал, например, signed var

Но думаю, что смысла использовать такое нет. Видел упоминание этого типа только в книге про си 91го года....

Comment: `register` - это не тип, а спецификатор класса хранения, как и `auto` (в C), `static`, `extern` и `_Thread_local`.

Comment: а с 17 плюсов это слово является зарезервированным и ничего не значит.

Comment: @EOF да, согласен, ошибся. Но сути, я думаю, это не меняет

Comment: да оно и в С ничего уже не означает

Comment: @user7860670 ну это да. но вопрос то был про то, что впринципе означает слово register

Comment: нет, вопрос был про тип переменной

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну если по буквам читать, то да. Но суть вопроса, как я понял, была в том, что человек не знает, что означает слово register, и, как следствие, какой тип у переменной

Comment: @TrifonovDmitriy, текст ответа поправьте, замените  `unsigned var`  на **`signed var;`** (кстати, заодно можете рассказать ТС, как программно отличать signed от unsigned)

Comment: @TrifonovDmitriy И еще, `register` всегда был хинтом (hint, совет). Компилятор не обязан помещать такую переменную в регистр, но вправе прислушаться к такому совету, по крайней мере при оптимизации  такая переменная будет более приоритетна для размещения в регистре, чем другие. / И еще, по крайней мере в старом Си тип int существовал по умолчанию (как минимум как тип возвращаемого функцией значения), поэтому его можно было не указывать вместе с хинтом

Comment: @avp Это интересно, не знал об этой информации,  спасибо! Но почему нужно изменить unsigned var на signed var? Я этот пример привел, чтобы показать, что можно написать unsigned без int, но все равно переменная var будет типа int. То есть, unsigned int var это по сути то же самое, что unsigned var

Comment: @TrifonovDmitriy, imho надо заменить для максимального совпадения типа. Оба же signed int (конечно, и signed  и unsigned можно писать без int)

Comment: @avp да, понял. Думаю, вы правы, нужно изменить, спасибо за совет.